# Segfault while running through onMessage in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm using activemq to pass xml messages between processes (c++ programs),and it works as needed. I'm trying to install the programs onto a new host and I'm running into trouble. Since I didn't configure my dev system, I'm fairly sure I've got a configuration problem in the new systems activemq instance. I'm getting a segfault when running a piece of code in the `onMessage` method. If I call the code before I launch the message listener, it runs fine. I can't show the code unfortunately...so pseudo code, sorry.

```
Main
{
    Declare object
    Use object.            <-- works fine
}
MessageReader
{
    onMessage
    {
         Declare object.    <-- segfaults here
    }
}
Main
{
    Declare messageReader 
    Run messageReader 
}
```

When program receives message, it segfaults when attempting to instantiate the object.

Both dev and deployment systems are running Linux 64, and the programs are compiled `-m64` as well. If the activemq c++ libraries were 32 bit builds, I would get elf failures when trying to link, correct? 
Stack limit is unlimited, `-Xms=1G` and `-Xmx=10G`, but I am getting some kind of warning about too few threads (from the console running activemq) which I've no idea about.
Any help would be appreciated, and yes I realise I really suck at describing things

Comment: What version of the client?  What OS?

Comment: Activemq snapshot 5.10, activemq cpp 3.8.2. Running system is red hat, failing system is suse. A couple changes to the code has it now failing as soon as I try to run the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided my guess is that it's related to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQCPP-529 but it's hard to say in your case.  The first thing to do is upgrade to v3.8.3 of the library to get the latest fixes.  Another thing to try is to crate the object on the heap via using new 'Object' and then delete it or assign it to an auto_ptr for automatic clean-up.

Comment: Thanks, will try upgrade of cpp library . I had already changed from stack to heap allocation and it failed in the malloc.

Comment: Afraid there's not much more that can be done from the outside, you'll have to start debugging on the failing node to see what's going on.

Comment: Updated to the new library (3.8.3), now the code is failing in lockThreadsLib ??? Going to have an aneurysm now

Comment: Started fresh - restarted activemq server, put a few messages up. Ran my code which fails to return from `connection->start()'

Comment: that would indicate that the client can't connect to the sever if using failover.

Answer (score 0):

Issues were caused by trying to stop and re-start the AMQ C++ library between uses (programmer feels shame)